Can a set be uncountable in one sense and countable in another sense?
Can a set be uncountable in one sense and countable in another sense? Or in other words are there senses in which the set of all real numbers satisfies the Peano Axioms? I ask because of the following, which is taken from Wikipedia: Being countable is not absolute. Skolem’s paradox is the seeming contradiction that the set of all real numbers is uncountable in one sense, and this is provable from ZFC or even from some small finite subsystem of ZFC. And in some models of ZFC, the set of all reals is countable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness_(logic)#:~:text=Other%20properties%20are%20not%20absolute,being%20a%20cardinal).

Yes. ZFC has countable models, so all sets in them will be finite or countable when viewed 'from outside', regardless of their internal cardinality. The latter is determined by maps available 'inside' the model only, and those may be limited. In fact, any  countable first-order theory that has an infinite model has a countable model (and a model of any given infinite cardinality). That is Löwenheim–Skolem theorem.

The point is that "my set X is countable" means "there exists a bijection between X and the natural numbers" (for any given fixed set representing the natural numbers, for instance the set of finite von Neumann ordinals, when that is available). It's not some magical thing that exists independently of the setting. In ZFC every function is also a set, and so it can be that your set X is in two models of ZFC, but only one of those models contains a set that encodes a bijection with the naturals.

But if you are playing around with axiomatic set theory, you have to say what you mean by "one sense" and "another sense". You also can't say "the" set of real numbers, because .... what is this set? In some set theories the set of Cauchy reals and the set of Dedekind reals aren't even isomorphic.
